# Adding conduits and barriers to friction surface in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization, cost-path

I am in the starting process of A LCP archaeological project and am still new to QGIS and I've hit a issue. I am adapting the methodology of [this](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272428/1-s2.0-S0305440313X0010X/1-s2.0-S030544031300294X/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIF5G6gC0AvA9qUTTluL5D9GVEtq6oi2YCxpyMCPeLC59AiEAr4CNlp0Ksa5EhVsrcpGdr71BRUn9pM5csTt9%2B8vhwS4qswUIcxAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDMNich67sNTSbQrQDyqQBayiKTjwMwHjbDe%2BDOHg5NVInyCAEWAN8ZAd33TaBkTG707wMZW07i9dToyfSrHgE0CD5%2FL5vOiWiAdaLoxmuPbuo9XIFXgh673q84cLT3znq1tPANbySwQqqWIzGPHdMq73goeDIiF6WBCvQRPBiyti9GpsUe3OyiR06%2Bo08ycVHM6BONR%2B7BztkozsMnblxlMabnTHsIMvdOlq0LocDnMl3bnOenp397nkoX1UsyggQKq1F04ixM2nMbC5u737LPkBQXv3taFiY5H7i3BFX%2FvNUQHOdOPbrYYFqaHnC9JJ7Ysdu9t7y8OIz3iPGJTjKhG7XHxhjGSu4Fzdy1neGiuBfsR8xMtvp39tz6kPbdw7MLNq9dhAbmKxKc8hpU8CI7zrsD90XV9VeMj1DFEi4Ue3jnTret0eyINYLrhddbYlg1TDeNMe%2Bje95pNEPuggPP%2BmEodZi2EumDCtuJGzSVH24nR37SztJz2IlnDyL1PiFdYAVeJNH4gpFGtHoK%2BRHyM0ILJtmMhQhrR5We0sOBKLURgU4PdobUvPOQK9IMwmX9w2rCvDFJQoBAvLMIetCyQ9hOJAc2CBJVQrzVWXCJfu%2Ba2RRRDLBv%2B0%2Ful3NxBKa7xDoyh5uP6HvrYZLC9iLJI%2FvJh8GK41GxG%2BXmrxJHxUeWM8z%2Fq0JzLSx7p4XG2OqrU4W7xs082wRxAnnF9uoKCo848ruKgPITXB6PSVIuAvrloxp%2BHtz2OlcEKWt48IYIZ92%2BeHPPP6A0LcT5IE1apiIKDONuIIx%2FfboYMRPDU0py9sgGRX0%2FYrVYk%2FomCK5uFjcIYaX2JcgLS5sYzuFlLWYxnSyy1USqhtInTC1OvNcJe7rin96fp6pSlrOXhoMJue%2BK0GOrEBSaOzXDxuNS2GjCIo%2B9acDz8exBugjzN0CephltjBB7HaworaAjI4yD1fD2Ac2yQHQIcYI%2FTOMBHsgHtOiyPkWBdF%2BwRs1yyrlvdRWrQxJ7HFJm3dI42vYD5hHwy1iEhavU4XTWjkq1iZl%2Fmg3%2FVf1UDfEXzg9MDUGTshvkj0t5mTHFTFdNKBfXWPSocgbpaxlTlvD3HIeFI1n%2F7HBrmlwC4pmd69j%2F%2BDXnZfnxhOhN%2Bw&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240203T104117Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY7EL4QWEV%2F20240203%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=29aaf70b7c9f32e89eb01fbc573f1f762ee3efc38227ad87b74af4bfcc38f432&hash=28ab141f3c41af651dbd04daabbaaf59e6e41618857aa7ae9ac69201bda26d2e&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S030544031300294X&tid=spdf-db35b7f7-31bc-40e9-be99-3f24517683bc&sid=caf8136e3590784f6a6beed0870313046c8dgxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=1d005b50060355065954&rr=84fa0f804c180763&cc=gb): and have almost immediately  hit a barrier. I am unable to create conduits and barriers based on my own structures and conduits. I have drawn them as polygons and tried to change them into rasters, but it either does not work or creates a large black square. When I have tried clipping a copy of the raster to the shape of the polygon it alters the information in band 1.

How would I add weighted barriers and conduits into QGIS?

Every time I have tried I have not been able to alter only the area within the polygons.